# C++ extern errors

Tags: c++

I have two cpp files each containing their own class. In my **main.c** file, I created a global declaration of those classes. I am getting an error in my **First.cpp** and **Second.cpp** inside the `F_method` and `S_method` where I try to reference that global class instance:

> In member function 'void First::F_method()': error: invalid use of
>   incomplete type 'class Second' note: forward declaration of 'class
>   Second'

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Main.c

```
#include "First.h"
#include "Second.h"
#include "Global.h"

First one;
Second two;


int main()
{

    while(1){
        one.F_method();
        two.S_method();
    }

}
```

Global.h

```
extern class First one;

extern class Second two;
```

First.cpp

```
#include "First.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Global.h"

using namespace std;

First::First()
{
    //Constructor
}


void First::F_method()
{
    std::cout << two.S_Var << std::endl;
}
```

First.h

```
#ifndef First_h
#define First_h


class First
{
public:
    First();

    void F_method();


   int F_Var = 66;
};
#endif
```

Second.cpp

```
#include "Second.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Global.h"

using namespace std;

Second::Second()
{
    //Constructor
}


void Second::S_method()
{
   std::cout << one.F_Var << std::endl;
}
```

Second.h

```
#ifndef Second_h
#define Second_h


class Second
{
public:
    Second();

    void S_method();


    int S_Var = 12;
};
#endif
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: In member function 'void First::F_method()':                                            error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Second'                                           note: forward declaration of 'class Second'

Comment: You need to add `#include "First.h"` in Second.cpp and `#include "Second.h"` in First.cpp.

Comment: It works R Sahu! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `two.S_Var` in `First::F_method()`, you don't have the full definition of `Second`. Similarly, when using `one.F_Var` in `Second::S_method()`, you don't have the full definition of `First`.

You need to add `#include "First.h"` in Second.cpp and `#include "Second.h"` in First.cpp.